# SQL Server BCP utility best separator character to use

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, bcp

I am sure many would came across this scenario.

Whenever we use SQL Server BCP utility to import/export data to-from delimited text files, which is the best `"Separator Character"` to use. We have Note-text kind of fields which can have , and now we found | & ~ is also used by our users in those fields.
Which character in your opinion has least chances of user ever used. Or you have better alternative to deal with this issue.

Update-
This software is being developed in UK-English users.

Comment: What encoding? What language? There's too many factors to guess.

Comment: This is asking for "it depends" answers. Choose the character that doesn't appear in the context of what you import. Only you can know the probability of a certain character being used. For all we know, you're importing data from the Tilda Appreciation Society.

Comment: If you use a format file, you can specify different delimiters for each field, or specify fixed length fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use non-printing characters - **ASCII code 2** and **ASCII code 3** are commonly used as START and STOP delimiters (STX/ETX) and are certain not to appear in user data.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to whatever character you select to use as separator should not come in any of your Text field, If your text field contain your separator character then replace it before you place your text into bcp export file. ^ or | are rarely used characters so use anyone of them as separator character and put check in your code to replace your separator character from your text field with some other character so it will not make any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Answer is that really depends on the data. One could use 
^ or # or ~ or |

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use two "weird" characters as separators in my csv files. I've had cases of people inserting data with a `|` and with a `#`. Something like `^|` or `|||` should be better.

It shouldn't be a problem doing it with BCP.